# Reload the new value assigned in a cookie using yii2

Tags: php, cookies, yii2

I have created a cookie like,

```
     $cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
     $testAry= array('val1' => '1212', 'val2' => '23456');
     $cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
        'name' => 'testAry',
        'value' => $testAry,
        'expire' => time() + 86400 * 365,
    ]));
```

Later,i have added a new value to the same cookie like this,

```
$testAry= array('val1' => '1212', 'val2' => '23456',val3=>'7894');
   $cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
        'name' => 'testAry',
        'value' => $testAry,
        'expire' => time() + 86400 * 365,
    ]));
```

The problem is that if i haven't clear my browser cookie ,I will get error as undefined index.The new value which i have set to the cookie is not updated.Please give a solution

Comment: This rather depends upon WHERE and HOW you amended the cookie. Also when you are checking it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i've modified your code and tried like this:

```
$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
$testAry= array('val1' => '1212', 'val2' => '23456');
$cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => 'testAry',
    'value' => $testAry,
    'expire' => time() + 86400 * 365,
]));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cookies->getValue('testAry'));
echo "</pre>";
unset($cookies);

$cookies = Yii::$app->response->cookies;
$testAry= array('val1' => '1212', 'val2' => '23456','val3'=>'7894');
$cookies->add(new \yii\web\Cookie([
    'name' => 'testAry',
    'value' => $testAry,
    'expire' => time() + 86400 * 365,
]));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($cookies->getValue('testAry'));
echo "</pre>";
unset($cookies);
```

and get this response:

```
Array
(
    [val1] => 1212
    [val2] => 23456
)

Array
(
    [val1] => 1212
    [val2] => 23456
    [val3] => 7894
)
```

Let me know if it helps